# How to add pre-processing and post-processing layers to a pre-trained model in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, pre-trained-model

I am working with a pre-trained model (complex_yolo), where we use it for object detection using LiDAR point cloud data. The input to the model is the BEV image. So to work with this model, first we convert the point cloud to BEV and then feed it to the model.
I was wondering if there is a way to do the BEV conversion as part of the model itself (by adding a custom layer to the model) instead of doing it as a pre-processing step?
Can we also have the post-processing step (where we perform non-maximum suppression to filter the detections) as part of the model itself?